# Laravel copy data from one model instance to another object (child of the first)

Tags: laravel-5, model

Supose this Eloquent Model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
}
```

And this one:

```
class DeletedUser extends User
{
    public function someDeletedUserFunction()
    {
        // ... some stuff here
    }
}
```

If I do `$user = User::find(1)` and `$deletedUser = new DeletedUser()`, how can I copy the data inside `$user` object to the `$deletedUser` object?

I am trying to use `$deletedUser->attributes = $user->getAttributes`, and it is fine, but I cant do it with original attributes and another internal object data.

How can achieve this?

**EDIT:**
Due to the confusing example I used (User and DeletedUser), I will use another example. Supose a main class Automobile. I want to build a Factory method find in order to retrieve an Automobile child, It could be AutomaticAutomobile or ManualAutomobile objects. So if I call `Automobile::find($id)` the method have to return an AutomaticAutomobile or ManualAutomobile instance. What I want to avoid Is to query db again, so I query for getting Automobile first object and then instantiate a child with the data of the Automobile object. Is this clearer example than previous?

See this code as an factory example:

```
class AutomobileFactory
{
    const MANUAL_AUTOMOBILE= 0;
    const AUTOMATIC_AUTOMOBILE= 1;

    static function create(int $rewardType, array $data)
    {
        switch($rewardType){
        case self::AUTOMATIC_AUTOMOBILE:
            return AutomaticAutomobile::create($data);
            break;
        case self::MANUAL_AUTOMOBILE:
            return ManualAutomobile::create($data);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Not supported");
        }
    }

    static function find(int $rewardType, int $id) : Reward
    {
        $automobile = Automobile::find($id);
        switch($rewardType){
        case self::AUTOMATIC_AUTOMOBILE:
            $automatic = someCopyMethods()... // Here I copy all the data
            return $automatic;
            break;
        case self::MANUAL_AUTOMOBILE:
            $manual= someCopyMethods()... // Here I copy all the data
            return $manual;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Not supported");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it not be better to use `softDeletes` in your User model. Then create a scope which only returns deleted users? I dont see the purpose of having a model specifically for deleted users to be honest.

Comment: It is only an example, it could be used with a Reward model, a Role model, a Automobile model, a Toy model, and more. Just figuring how to do it.

Comment: I wouldnt use this method. Essentially you are saving deleted data again which doesnt make sense if deleting it from one table to begin with. Better to add a `deleted_at` field, use softDeletes trait and then call deleted records when needed. Laravel does not add deleted items to model queries so you'd be safe not mixing the two.

Comment: Would you like me to explain in an answer?

Comment: I edited my question with a new example.

Answer (score 0):

If AutomaticAutomobile and ManualAutomobile are childs of Automobile, why won't you just do it like:

```
 static function find(int $rewardType, int $id) : Reward
    {
        switch($rewardType){
        case self::AUTOMATIC_AUTOMOBILE:
            $automatic = AutomaticAutomobile::find($id); 
            return $automatic;
            break;
        case self::MANUAL_AUTOMOBILE:
            $manual= ManualAutomobile::find($id);
            return $manual;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Not supported");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mainly because is a Factory design pattern, so is the factory class who has to decide which of them instantiate. In the other hand, my question is how to do that, not how to avoid it.